# How to "return" an input of a function, with out using a function on the input? (Racket)

Tags: functional-programming, return, racket

**Intro**

Hi, I'm new to Racket and new to functional languages, therefore it is hard for me to do even simple things (especially when there is not too much material in the internet)

**Actual question:**

I am starting to write a function that gives the max and min of a list. Therefore the function receives 2 vars one is the list and the second is a list that holds in it only 2 vars the max and the min. 
Then when "list" is null that means I went over all the vars of the list. This means I want to "return" the list of maxMin, but ofcourse functional languages don't work this way.

How to do this?

Here is the idea of what I am trying to achieve:

```
#lang pl
(define (maxMin list maxiMini)
  (if (null? list)
      ;return the max and min from list when finished looking at the list
      (maxiMini)
       ; else do other things
      )
  )
```

Comment: Is this homework? Are you using a particular textbook?

Comment: Hi @AlexisKing , yes the question of finding max and min of a list is HW, but I am asking not for solving the HW question, but rather the concept of how to "return" an input var in a functional language. We do not have a text book.

Comment: I ask because asking how to “return” something in a functional programming language is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188673), and it betrays a lack of knowledge of how to structure functional programs. Consider reading some of [*How to Design Programs*](http://www.htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/) to learn a principled way to design functional programs. Specifically, [Part II, Arbitrarily Large Data](http://www.htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/part_two.html) explains a recipe for writing functions that process lists.

Comment: Thanks! loved the XY problem link, first time I saw this definition. So I understand that trying to give a return value is trying to solve X with Y while Y is not connected since functional languages don't work this way. Do you have a link for a right way of thinking in functional languages or a way how to go around the return problem (while I understand that the latter is less favourable)?

Comment: I think the links I provided to *How to Design Programs* are the references you’re looking for, though I admit they are rather heavy reading for something that ought to be provided by the class you are taking. Since I see you’re using `#lang pl`, perhaps [the lecture notes on Racket on Eli’s website](https://pl.barzilay.org/lec03.html) would be helpful in a considerably less verbose format. That said, I don’t think there are many shortcuts here—if you’re not familiar with functional programming, and you need to use a functional programming language, you’re probably going to need to learn FP.

Comment: Thanks! yeah they looked heavy thats why I asked for more. I will look into Eli's website. Also hope that I will have time to dive deeper into this philosophy but hope not to do so if under pressure :-)

Comment: So, I don't know what language `pl` is, but I do feel compelled to say that Racket is not 'just' a functional programming language. But (per the wikipedia article) it "is a general purpose, multi-paradigm programming language in the Lisp-Scheme family"

Thus, I think that the right way to do early returns in Racket is a fine question. Although I admit I'm also predisposed to also think its a fine thing to ask for functional programs in general.

However, I'm not familiar with the `pl` language per se. So I guess it could have semantics that are radically different than what I'm used too.

Comment: Lets say you have `(if p 1 2)` this will "return" the result of the if expression. if `p` is not false it will "return" 1, other wise 2. Since everything is expressions it always return as long as it is the tail expression.. `(begin some-expression 5)` will always "return" 5 after evaluating `some-expression` which needs to have side effect in order to not be dead code. Be carefull with enclosing in parenthesis. If  the variable `maxiMini` is a list `(maxiMini)` calls `maxiMini` as a function. eg. the variable `car` is a fucntion and thus `(car '(1))` works.

Comment: just omit the parens. you don't need them there: `(define (maxMin list maxiMini)
  (if (null? list)
      maxiMini #| HERE!! |# 
      )
  )`. Anything that is evaluated *last* by a function, is that function's returned value, overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that returns something:

```
(define (min a b)
  (if (< a b)
      a
      b))
```

This "returns" the result of the `if`. The `if` "returns" either the evaluation of `a` or `b` based on what `(< a b)` "returns".

I write "returns" in quotes since in lisp langauges on usually say "the expression evaluates to". Imagine this:

```
(min 5 10)
```

The expression above evaluates to 5.. If you were to put the result in another expression:

```
(+ (min 5 10) 1)
```

Then `(min 5 10)` evaluates to `5`, which is the first value `+` gets applied with along with `1` and it then evaluates to `6`.

Also note that the **variable** `<` evaluates to a function and thus tryng to call it like `(< 4 5)` works, but `a` and `b` are numbers and cannot be called like `(a)`. It just won't work. If you are familiar with algol languages it is the same as haveing the variable `a`, which is a number, and doing `a()` with it.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a [continuation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conts.html). (As a side note, using Racket's [exception handling](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/exns.html) system would also work here. Bonus points if you can rewrite the code here to use `with-handlers` instead of `let/ec`.)

While most uses of continuations, are really too powerful, this particular pattern is fairly standard, and IMO one of the few good uses for them. Basically, continuations are like control flow statements in C like languages (`break`, `continue`, `return`, `goto`, `yield`, etc), except in those languages, those control flow statements are keywords, where as in Racket, continuations are first class values.

That means you can technically return, say, another functions return statement, and when calling it the code jumps to roughly its state when the first return would return to. As a result, you can make a generator pattern. You can see how this can get very complicated very fast if you're not careful.

However, if you don't ever want to 'return' (so to speak) a continuation, you can use a much simpler (and lighter weight) escape continuation. These work very similarly to `setjump` and `longjmp` in C. You can use them to return from an inner context, but if the control flow leaves the scope of the escape continuation the stack can't be recreated. (Basically, escape continuations can pop stack frames, but they can't restore the like regular continuations.)

Racket has a nice form for creating escape continuations `let/ec`, which creates an escape continuation. When called, the whole expression evaluates to the value given to the escape continuation. For example, the following function would normally evaluate to `4`:

```
(define (looper)
  3
  4)

> (looper)
4
```

But if we insert an escape continuation (let's call it `return`), it does an early return from the function, thus causing it to evaluate to 3:

```
(define (looper2)
  (let/ec return
    (return 3)
    4))

> (looper2)
3
```

You can see how you can embed this in a large function where you do want an early return:

```
(define (large-function)
  (let/ec return 
    ... lots of code ...
    (when some-condition
      (return some-value))
    ... lots of code ...))
```

Of course, most of the time when you want an early return like this, its because of some exceptional state, which is why I highly recommend you just use Racket's exception handling system. You can throw an exception with [`raise`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=raise#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._raise%29%29), and catch one with [`with-handlers`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=with-handlers#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._with-handlers%29%29).

Comment: I think this is overkill. Usually you have `return` as a keyword in other languages while expression languages "return" whatever the result is. If I met with continuations the first months learning lisp my mind probably would have melted :-p